# Apache PostreSQL database server only

Tags: centos, ssh, apache-httpd, remote, postgresql

I was wondering if it's possible to use apache to make a postgresql database available for connections from the web without using a website to interface with the database.

Instead of having a webpage running on apache and the webpage is connecting to the postgresql database with php I'd like it so that a linux computer on a different network can ssh connect to the postgresql database.

I may not be making sense but I am battling to explain what I need.

In a nutshell I need a web application to connect to a postgresql database running on an internal network and I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

In the past I have done this using openvpn where the client machine uses openvpn to connect to the internal network and then connect to postgresql using the servers IP but I need to do this without using OpenVPN

Comment: Set up an ssh server and "a linux computer on a different network can ssh connect to the postgresql database.". Or run pgsql not on localhost but on `0:port`

Comment: is it possible to make an ssh connection available to the internet?

Comment: You could then use phpPgAdmin as your web-based client too.

Comment: @Trent Sure it is.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239428/postgresql-accessible-to-web-application . You can update your question there - indeed, you are encouraged to do so. I'm amending my answer there.

Comment: You cannot use Apache as a SSH server (any more than Apache can be a SMTP server or a RDP server), because Apache is a HTTP server. Beyond that, this would probably make a lot more sense if you simply stated the requirements.

Comment: ok wow now I know what I need to do, make ssh to my server available online, can anyone recommend some instructions or documentation on how to achieve this?